# Change(replace) file within reference

Tags: python, maya

I need to replace an OLD file with a NEW file within a reference. There is a **referenceEdit** command but no flags for replacing a file.

so ideally I need sth like:

```
cmds.referenceQuery( myReference, e=1, file=NEW )
```

Answer (score 7):

You should be able to replace references by using the `file` command.

Assuming your reference node's name is known (otherwise you can retrieve it via `referenceQuery`) and the name is `myReferenceRN`, you can do:

```
from maya import cmds
cmds.file("/path/to/new/reference/file.mb", loadReference="myReferenceRN")
```

This will update the file path which `myReferenceRN` currently points to, with the one you specify as the first argument of the `file` command (in this case, `/path/to/new/reference/file.mb`).