# partial, getting some data from textField

Tags: python, maya

```
import maya.cmds as cmds
from functools import partial

def export(txtField):
    print "hello"
    #print cmds.textField( txtField, q=1 )

if cmds.window( 'exporter', q=1, ex=1 ):
    cmds.deleteUI( 'exporter' )
window = cmds.window( 'exporter' )
cmds.columnLayout( adjustableColumn=True )
name = cmds.textField( text='testing...' )
press = cmds.button( 'Export...', c=partial( export, name) )
cmds.showWindow( 'exporter' )
```

So Im getting error:

```
# Error: export() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given) #
```

So Im new to partial and I dont understand what they do and how they work. But I know it's possible to do what I want with partial. So just print out whatever I have in textField

Comment: the reply is below; just out of curiosity (I hope it is ok to ask in a comment, as it is unrelated) did you manage to have this working? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44703839/changereplace-file-within-reference
I'm still quite new to SO as an active user and I'm not sure if I'm supposed to keep track of answers which were not explicitly accepted...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case `partial` is probably overkill.  @mapofemergence's answer will work fine, but you can just do this:

```
from maya import cmds    

if cmds.window('exporter', q=1, ex=1):
    cmds.deleteUI('exporter')

window = cmds.window('exporter')
cmds.columnLayout(adjustableColumn=True)
tf = cmds.textField(text='testing...')
def export(*_):
    print "textfield says" , cmds.textField(tf, q=1, text=1)

press = cmds.button('Export...', c=export)
cmds.showWindow('exporter')
```

since `export` is defined after the textfield is created, it captures the variable value at creation time.

Comment: Thank you @theodox. Btw what is *_?

Comment: buttons always fire their commands with an argument (which is almost always 'False').  99% of the time you just ignore it.  `*_` is python short hand for "take argments here, but I'm going to ignore them later"

Answer (score 1):

Here's something which should work for you:

```
from maya import cmds
from functools import partial

def export(txtField, *args):
    print txtField, ':', args
    print cmds.textField(txtField, q=1, text=1)

if cmds.window('exporter', q=1, ex=1):
    cmds.deleteUI('exporter')

window = cmds.window('exporter')
cmds.columnLayout(adjustableColumn=True)
name = cmds.textField(text='testing...')
press = cmds.button('Export...', c=partial(export, name))
cmds.showWindow('exporter')
```

What is happening (and might be confusing) is that the command invoked by Maya's button already passes an argument by default, in this case `False`. As a consequence, `partial` is appending the extra argument to the one you specified and therefore `export` is expected to receive two arguments, not just one.

It is quite some time I don't use native Maya UI commands, so I'm not sure what `False` stands for and if you can expect any meaningful argument to be passed, in different conditions.
Anyway, you can work around this by adding an extra argument to your function definition.

You could write something like `def export(txtField, _):` but that would only work if you're sure that the parameter being passed is one and only one. For that reason I used `def export(txtField, *args):` instead. This way you can print `args` and troubleshoot what's being passed (regardless the number of arguments), while having the rest of your code working.

As a side note, for other uses of `partial` with Maya you might want to read this:
https://theodox.github.io/2014/maya_callbacks_cheat_sheet